# Cómo hacer en c++para que me devuelva una nombre a partir de una letra introducida?

Tags: c++, if

Acá dejo el código pero me da error en el `else`.

La idea esta orientada a minoácidos, cuando introduzca la letra por ejemplo `v`, el programa debe devolver `valina`. Gracias por toda la ayuda

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
int main (int argc, char* argv[], string)
{ char o, aminoacido, valina,isoleucina,leucina,lisina,metionoina, fenilalanina,
treonina, triptofano, histidina,
arginina, alanina, tirosina, aspartato, cisteina, glutamato,
glutamina, glicina, prolina, serina, asparagina, v, i,a, l, m, f, h,
c, g, p, s;
cout<<"Solo puede introducir una letra, Entre la letra: ";
cin>>o;
if (l=='v')
 {
cout<<"El aminoacido es: valina";
}

if (o=='i');
{
cout<<"El aminoacido es: isoleucina";
}

if (o=='a');
{
cout<<"El aminoacido es: alanina, arginina y aspartato";
  }

if (o=='l');
 {
cout<<"El aminoacido es: leucina, licina";
}

if (o=='m');
{
cout<<"El aminoacido es: metionina";
}

if (o=='f');
 {
cout<<"El aminoacido es: fenilalanina";
}
if (o=='t');
 {
cout<<"El aminoacido es: treonina, triptofano, tirosina";
 }

if (o=='h');
 {
cout<<"El aminoacido es: histidina";
}
if (o=='c');
 {
cout<<"El aminoacido es: cisteina";
}
if (o=='g');
 {
cout<<"El aminoacido es: glutamato, glutaina, glicina";
}
if (o=='p');
 {
cout<<"El aminoacido es: prolina";
}
if (o=='s');
 {
cout<<"El aminoacido es: serina";
}
     else
 {
 cout<< "Solo puede introducir las letras v, i,a, l, m, f, h, c, g, p, s" <<end;
}
system("color 6");
system( "pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seleccionar mediante un `if` es tedioso y propenso a errores, seleccionar mediante un `switch` es más eficiente, menos propenso a errores pero poco práctico de mantener, así que mi consejo es usar un mapa.

#### Propuesta

Con un mapa cuya clave sea la letra y cuyo valor sea una lista de aminoácidos, puedes rellenarlo en tiempo de ejecución así:

```
std::string nombres[] {"valina",    "isoleucina", "alanina",
                       "arginina",  "aspartato",  "leucina",
                       "licina",    "metionina",  "fenilalanina",
                       "treonina",  "triptofano", "tirosina",
                       "histidina", "cisteina",   "glutamato",
                       "glutaina",  "glicina",    "prolina",
                       "serina"};

using aminoacidos = std::list<std::string>;
std::map<char, aminoacidos> items;

for (const auto &aminoacido : nombres)
{
    auto [i, b] = items.emplace(aminoacido.front(), aminoacidos{});
    i->second.emplace_back(aminoacido);
}
```

Con dicho mapa, la búsqueda es muy sencilla:

```
std::cout << "Solo puede introducir una letra, Entre la letra: ";
std::cin >> letra;

if (auto aminoacido = items.find(letra); aminoacido == items.end())
//     buscar por letra --> ~~~~~~~~~~~
{
    // Letra no encontrada
    std::cout << "Solo puede introducir las letras ";
    for (const auto &i : items) std::cout << i.first << ", ";
    std::cout << '\n';
    break;
}
else
{
    // Letra encontrada
    std::cout << "El aminoacido es: ";
    for (const auto &a : aminoacido->second) std::cout << a << ", ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

La ventaja de esta aproximación es que la lista es fácilmente ampliable con muy pocos cambios en el código. Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7Q5zOugJMbAmNUGk)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Para estos casos existe el condicional switch, que hace lo mismo que un monton de condicionales if seguidos.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   char entrada;
   string salida;
   cin>>entrada;


switch (entrada)  
  {  
     case 'l':  
        salida = "El aminoacido es: leucina, licina";
        break;
     case 'm':  
        salida = "El aminoacido es: metionina";
        break;
     default:  
        salida = "Solo puede introducir las letras v, i,a, l, m, f, h, c, g, p, s" ;
        break;
  }  

cout<<salida;
}
```

lo que estas haciendo es introduciendo un char **entrada** para despues analizar según la condicion switch, dependiendo de para cada caso, estas declarando la variable salida como una u otra.

El método que sigue esta sentencia es el de analizar la igualdad, y despues ejecutar lo que viene a continuación de los dos puntos (en este caso la asignacion de la salida a una frase) y después ejecutando al sentencia break para que se detenga ahí y salga del condicional switch, todo esto para finalmente mostrar por pantalla el string salida el cual hemos modificado previamente.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77558/discussion-on-answer-by-kevin-m-como-hacer-en-cpara-que-me-devuelva-una-nombr).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (l=='v')
 {
cout<<"El aminoacido es: valina";
}
```

Creo que ahí está el error, deber ser `o=='v'`, por que o es la variable de entrada, de lo contrario en esa linea no esta verificando la entrada del usuario sino alguna otra entrada.

Comment: Faltaria mas, muchas gracias a ti tio

Comment: Thanks you are the BOSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Si es muy interesante la otra resuesta .Gracias, me di cuenta en el codigo de arriba, no hace falta declarar los aminoacidos, ni las iniciales, ni el string salida, si al final yo devuelvo las respuestas con el cout, en forma de oración no de caracteres , es texto, nos variable